# MSIX Installation failed: Common::Deployment::MsixvcStagingSession::GetManifestReader in MsixvcStagingSession failed with error 0x80070570

Tags: windows, winui-3, msix, appinstaller

I'm distributing my MSIX packaged software from GitHub. However, some random users are not able to install the msix package with error code 0x80070570.

package can be found at https://github.com/DGP-Studio/Snap.Hutao/releases/tag/1.9.1

When using `Add-AppxPackage` command, it throw out the same error with app installer.

```
Add-AppxPackage : 部署失败，原因是 HRESULT: 0x80073CF0, 无法打开包。
MsixvcStagingSession 中的 Common::Deployment::MsixvcStagingSession::GetManifestReader 失败，出现错误 0x80070570。
注意: 有关其他信息，请在事件日志中查找 [ActivityId] cfb20c9e-366a-0005-de3e-b2cf6a36da01，或使用命令行 Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID cfb20c9e
-366a-0005-de3e-b2cf6a36da01
所在位置 行:1 字符: 1
+ Add-AppxPackage .\Snap.Hutao.1.9.1.msix
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (D:\Desktop\Snap.Hutao.1.9.1.msix:String) [Add-AppxPackage], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

---

Keep trakcing the ActivityID, I got more details

```
Time                      ID           Message
----                      --           -------
2023/12/24 21:32:46       603          已使用主参数 Snap.Hutao.1.9.1.msix 以及选项 0 和 0 开始对程序包执行部署 Add 操作。要获取有关诊断应用部
                                       署问题的帮助，请参阅 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160。
2023/12/24 21:32:46       495          MsixvcStagingSession 中的 Common::Deployment::MsixvcStagingSession::GetManifestReader 失败，出现错误 0
                                       x80070570。
2023/12/24 21:32:46       402          错误 0x80070570: 从位置 Snap.Hutao.1.9.1.msix 中读取部件清单(manifest)失败，错误为: 文件或目录损坏且无
                                       法读取。
                                       。
2023/12/24 21:32:46       404          程序包  的 AppX 部署操作失败，错误为 0x80073CF0。此失败的具体错误文本是: MsixvcStagingSession 中的 Com
                                       mon::Deployment::MsixvcStagingSession::GetManifestReader 失败，出现错误 0x80070570。
```

---

The final error code was `0x80073CF0`, based on the [Microsoft documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/troubleshooting?redirectedfrom=MSDN), system logs are required.

We found the installation raised 216 event ID warning: `App manifest validation warning: Declared namespace`

[screenshot of eventviewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l82b4.png)

I can't fine more instructions on how to handle this error.

What I have tried:

1. Verified the file hash
2. Checked all dependencies are installed and up-to-date
3. Windows App Installer is also in the latest version
4. `%userprofie%\AppData\Local\Packages\60568DGPStudio.SnapHutao_wbnnev551gwxy` is cleaned

Reporting users are under multiple versions of Windows between Windows 10 22H2 and Windows 11 22H2.